# Using Trigger on body

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a variable being set in a plugin JS file, and in my own custom JS file, I'm calling the same event to piggypack on the developers work.

The issue is I need to access a variable set in the plugin javascript event.  It's currently being set as follows in the plugin JS:

```
$('#link').live('click', function() {
  var test = 123456;
  var another = 'string';

  $('body').trigger({
    'test' : test,
    'another' : another
  });
});
```

Now, in my own custom JS, I'm calling the same method on the `#link` to add my own code to execute.

```
$('#link').on('click', function(){
  // I need to access the another variable set previously
});
```

What I don't really get is when the jquery docs say that the trigger method is passing arguments to the event handler.  What does that mean exactly?  How would I access the variable set in a previous event?

Thanks in advance as always.

Comment: You use .trigger() to do just that, trigger an event on something. You pass .trigger() a string that tells it which event to fire (eg: 'click', or 'mouseenter') OR an actual "event" object. Here it has been passed an object with 2 properties 'test', and 'another'. That won't do anything. Furthermore, accessing a plugins variables is almost never a good idea. If you tell us what you're actually trying to do we might be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: In this particular event in the plugin, the author performs a .get() parses the JSON, and sets a few variables.  I'd like to access those same variables in my event that I also want to fire at the same time, so he instructed me that that's why he included the ('body') trigger.  I figured I just didn't know how to use it.

Comment: I'm basically trying to avoid duplicate .get() requests and just access the data returned in the first event by the plugin.  I guess I'm approaching this wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the plugin?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  It's a commercial one and I don't have authorization to share the code. :(

Comment: Don't have authorization to share javascript? As soon as you turn your page on it will be live to the world, there is no such thing as "secret" javscript. In any matter, the answer to your question is "for the most part, no, you can't access anything in an event handler unless someone has allowed you a way to hook into it". This is where the source to the plugin comes in, if the author has exposed any hooks by returning object references or allowing callbacks then you might be able to get in and do what you want to do. More likely you'll need to edit a poorly written plugin. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NORMALLY, you would pass extra parameters to an event, IF it has a custom event, you can access that:

```
$('#link').live('click', function() {
    var test = 123456;
    var another = 'string';
    $('body').trigger('HIT',{
        'test': test,
        'another': another
    });
});

$('body').on('HIT', function(e,param1) {
    $('#hitter').append('hi');
    $('#hitter').append(param1.test);
});
```

after this HIT event, the value of #hitter would have "hi123456" appended to it.  To access the "another" is simply param1.another, which returns "string".

Comment: This seems to do the trick.  Thanks!  I found out that I could use a custom event like you've done and added each item from the plugins trigger method as params to access them again in the new method.